# Prometheus monitor errors with isilon exporter

Tags: prometheus-node-exporter

I am testing a Prometheus server (v2.46.0) with an [isilon exporter](https://github.com/paychex/prometheus-isilon-exporter/tree/master) and having some trouble with pulling metrics. The isilon node is running 9.x API, which I've listed the issues below.

**The export is setup locally on the prometheus server as follows**

```
type hereprometheus-isilon-exporter -url http://10.120.71.9
```

**Prometheus configuration for the exporter is setup as follows: (this is the only exporter setup)**

```
- job_name: isilon-exporter-stats
  scrape_interval: 2m
  scrape_timeout: 1m
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - 127.0.0.1:9437
```

**The issue I am having (is being reported) is the following duplicate data:**

```
An error has occurred while serving metrics:

3736 error(s) occurred:
* collected metric "emcisi_cluster_hard_quota" { label:<name:"clustername" value:"itisimdcp12" > label:<name:"path" value:"/ifs/mdcp12/o2/data2/bch/surg/vakili" > gauge:<value:0 > } was collected before with the same name and label values
* collected metric "emcisi_cluster_advisory_quota" { label:<name:"clustername" value:"itisimdcp12" > label:<name:"path" value:"/ifs/mdcp12/o2/data2/bch/surg/vakili" > gauge:<value:0 > } was collected before with the same name and label values
* collected metric "emcisi_cluster_logical_used" { label:<name:"clustername" value:"itisimdcp12" > label:<name:"path" value:"/ifs/mdcp12/o2/data2/bch/surg/vakili" > gauge:<value:158 > } was collected before with the same name and label values
* collected metric "emcisi_cluster_physical_used" { label:<name:"clustername" value:"itisimdcp12" > label:<name:"path" value:"/ifs/mdcp12/o2/data2/bch/surg/vakili" > gauge:<value:32768 > } was collected before with the same name and label values
* collected metric "emcisi_cluster_hard_quota" { label:<name:"clustername" value:"itisimdcp12" > label:<name:"path" value:"/ifs/mdcp12/o2/data2/bch/surg/vakili" > gauge:<value:0 > } was collected before with the same name and label values
* collected metric "emcisi_cluster_advisory_quota" { label:<name:"clustername" value:"itisimdcp12" > label:<name:"path" value:"/ifs/mdcp12/o2/data2/bch/surg/vakili" > gauge:<value:0 > } was collected before with the same name and label values
* collected metric "emcisi_cluster_logical_used" { label:<name:"clustername" value:"itisimdcp12" > label:<name:"path" value:"/ifs/mdcp12/o2/data2/bch/surg/vakili" > gauge:<value:1.059706014417e+12 > } was collected before with the same name and label values
* collected metric "emcisi_cluster_physical_used" { label:<name:"clustername" value:"itisimdcp12" > label:<name:"path" value:"/ifs/mdcp12/o2/data2/bch/surg/vakili" > gauge:<value:6.31961452544e+11 > } was collected before with the same name

....
```

**I am accessing these metrics as follows (for testing):**

```
http://prometheus01:9437/metrics
```

I have tried change the scrape interval (increase the time), which produced the same errors.
I've experienced the same behavior when testing in multi mode with the isilon exporter.

Thank you

Comment: First of all, this question being about setting up an exporter is off-topic for SO. Something like [devops.se] or maybe one of [su] or [sf] would be more appropriate (consult their respective help pages to find which is best suited for your case).

Comment: That being said, it feels like error you encountering is caused by incorrect behavior of exporter itself. Maybe you have two something (disks, RAIDs, something of that matter) that it tries to expose data about, but fails to include label to differentiate between them. Consider filing an issue in their repository: it most likely will be even better approach them re-ask on another site of SE network.